# Objective-c Adding dynamic elements with necessary delegate methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an application where each screen will be added dynamically, along with all the elements on the screen, i.e, table, textfields etc. Each viewController will be using the same NIB, basically I loop through the JSON and for every new screen, I create a new ViewController object and add it to an array, and I do the same thing for the objects to be added to the screen.

The thing is, one screen may need a tableView delegate methods, another may need the text field delegate methods. If I don't have the delegates implemented in interface file, then I can't do this

```
 textField.delegate = self;
```

or

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
```

as it will flag an error.

Would it be bad practice, just to add all the delegate methods that I am likely to have, i.e.

```
@interface Testing : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>
```

and then implement all the methods, that way it would only call them if they were needed. Or would this be bad idea?

Or is there a better way to set this up?

Any information would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One shotgun approach is to strip the type off the delegate:

```
textField.delegate = (id) self;
```

If the delegate is somehow guaranteed to respond to the messages as required by the protocol, then everything will work fine. Whether this is an ugly hack or an elegant solution depends on the details of your problem.

Comment: Ah that seems to work just fine, was unaware I could do this. Could any issues arrise from using this solution? Or anything I should be aware of if I decide to use this solution? (Will accept your answer when I can, have to wait 10 mins)

Comment: Oh as for the other part of my question, do you think it would be bad practice to implement all the required delegate methods. They will only be called if that particular screen requires them. I know it would make the class quite large, but not sure if I have much choice

Comment: This is just a trick to get over the typing check during compilation. You’re saying “whatever self is, it’s going to be fine, trust me”. And as I said, if the object will conform to the protocol, everything will just work during runtime. ¶ I can’t say if implementing all the delegate methods in your class makes sense. I would try to find a different solution that would allow me to break the code into smaller chunks, but your use case is kind of special, so it’s hard to come with a decent solution without knowing and thinking about it more.

Comment: I will try and think of a better solution if I can, it is a unique use case, soI am trying to think of good ways of setting it up, but for time being if it works, I am happy enough. Once I have got the framework fleshed out, I will see if I can think of a more eloquent solution. Thanks for the help and information, much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can implement the required delegate methods and they will be called whenever required. Its always the preferred approach.